# Combining the results from 2 indexes in splunk query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-sdk

I have one index idx1 and other index idx2 and a common column "A" on which matching needs to be done.

I'm facing difficulty in combining the data from both the columns.
I've to combine the data in such a way that if there is duplicate then the data from idx1 must be prioritized over data from idx2; i.e. basically equivalent of set operation [a+(b-a)].

I've tried the following :

```
| set diff  [ search index=idx2 sourcetype=src | dedup A ] [search index=idx1 sourcetype=src | dedup A ]
| stats count BY index A
| table index A
```

Here I get total 10840 statistics with both columns filled.

But when I want to display other columns from both the indexes I get empty columns for those.

Upon executing :

```
| set diff  [ search index=1idx1 sourcetype=src | dedup A ] [search index=idx2 sourcetype=src | dedup A ]
    | stats count BY index
```

I get the output as

index     count
idx1      4791
idx2      6049

Can anyone help me how should I proceed??

I've tried even this but not sure

```
index=idx1 sourcetype=src
| append [
| set diff  [ search index=idx2 sourcetype=src | dedup A ] [search index=idx1 sourcetype=src | dedup A ]]
    | stats count BY index A
    | table index A
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are fields common to both event types then you can use a left join to combine the data.  This is *slow* and subject to a limit of 50,000 results.

```
index=1idx1 sourcetype=src | dedup A 
| join type=outer A [search index=idx2 sourcetype=src | dedup A]
| ...
```

A more performant way to merge results is with the `stats` command, but that doesn't honor the requirement that index A trump index B.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this :

```
index=idx1 sourcetype=src
| append [search index=idx2 sourcetype=src ]
| dedup A| table A B C D
```

idx1 had 4791 events

idx2 had 6049 events

(idx1-idx2) has 2590 events

(idx2-idx1) has 3848 events

union of 2 indexes has 8639 events

intersection of 2 indexes has 2201 events

So after executing the above query I got 8639 events

2590+3848+2201=8639

I think its correct...

Any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: The `dedup` command keeps the first occurrence of each value of field A and discards all others.  In the example query, idx1 comes first so matching values of A from idx2 are dropped, which means any corresponding values of fields B, C, and D will not be used.  This may or may not be intended.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by "any corresponding values of fields B, C, and D will not be used. This may or may not be intended."

Comment: "Correct" depends on what you want the final result to be.  That's not clear.

If the `append` produces two events:
`Index1 A E F G`
and `Index2 A B C D`
then the `dedup` will discard the second row, leaving only `Index1 A E F G`.

Comment: What would be best way to prioritize idx1 over idx2 in case if there are duplicates?

Comment: Use a left join as in the other answer.